# Regarding links to U&L questions in answers, and the way they do/don't expand to the title of the question

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, formatting

I sometimes refer to "canonical questions" in my answers, and I've noticed that while I'm writing the answer, the preview of the text shows the actual title of the linked question rather than the URL, even though I've only pasted in a plain URL with no extra formatting, *which is a nice feature*.

However, once I submit the answer, those same links revert to being rendered as ordinary URLs again.

`Example: I paste in the link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su`

In the preview I can now see the above line rendered as

Example: I paste in the link [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)

... but when I submit it, it will invariably revert to a plain URL<sup>1</sup>.

I obviously know about inserting links using the `[link text](link URL)` syntax, but since the preview is doing such a good job of showing the title of questions when linking to them with the URL only, I think it's a bit of a shame that this doesn't carry over from the preview to the submitted answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I'm almost 75% certain (i.e. "I seem to remember, but I may be wrong") that I've seen the formatting of links persist to the submitted answer occasionally, but never recently.</sub>

Comment: Yes, yes you have seen it! So have I and I thought I must have had a userscript or something that I've since removed. Thanks for confirming I'm not entirely gone yet!

Comment: It may be related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292100/213575

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s not something I’ve noticed recently (and I *think* I’ve used question links in some of my recent answers...). One thing I have noticed is that  questions are replaced by their title, whether the long or short URL is used:

- [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)
- [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/86440)

but answers aren’t (which sort of makes sense since they don’t have a separate title — but it would be nice if they were replaced):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218175/86440

I just saw the issue occur when editing [permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions)’s tag wiki. I added a link to a question, and as long as the tag wiki was open in the editor, the preview showed all the questions titles; but saving the edit would invariably result in a list of question links, with only the new link replaced with its title. It turns out all the old links used `http://`, and the new one used `https://`; changing all the links to `https://` fixed the issue.

Comment: My issue has been resolved. I can't remember exactly (it was over a year ago now), but I think that I was using `http` instead of `https`.